# how to use data to update something with findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, request, find

I'm looking to update something in my DB, but I need to use data in the object in the DB.

Here is what I would like to do :

```
score.findOneAndUpdate({name: "global"}, {$set:{score: score+1}})
```

and here is what it looks like in DB :

```
{
  name: "global"
  score: 1
}
```

So I need to find global, and increment the score by one and update it to obtain

```
{
 name: "global"
 score: 2
}
```

I know that I could first, find and store the data, and after an update, but how can I do it once with findAndUpdate()?

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use the [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator to increment the `score` field:

```
score.findOneAndUpdate({ name: "global" }, { $inc: { score: 1 } });
```

Comment: Thanks ! It really helped me !

Comment: Great to hear. Mark the answer is it helped resolve your issue.